# convert dataframe to matrix in R

Tags: r

I am beginner in R.

I have an input in dataframe like this:

```
> str(new.dataframe)
'data.frame':   86 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ U89355_at       : num  66.8 84.6 136.4 105 103 ...
 $ U01877_at       : num  408 306 370 449 268 ...
 $ X84709_at       : num  318 636 1005 427 462 ...
 $ M58603_at       : num  942 616 730 592 566 ...
 $ M69043_at       : num  3479 1735 5544 1842 2243 ...
 $ L19067_at       : num  688 1012 1238 753 656 ...
 $ U33838_at       : num  -27.3 7.5 22 24 -8 -27.2 -36 -11.1 -34.8 23 ...
 $ U33838_s_at     : num  176 312 426 305 216 ...
 $ Z22951_rna1_s_at: num  438 854 937 572 480 ...
 $ M58286_s_at     : num  961 851 252 1149 1361 ...
 $ M32315_at       : num  716 466 460 819 589 ...
 $ X02910_at       : num  39.8 62.7 37.8 48.5 57 75.9 55.1 32 22 5.4 ...
 $ L41690_at       : num  546 1246 652 913 602 ...
 $ U78798_at       : num  61.4 91 118 165.1 95 ...
 $ U50062_at       : num  125 226 185 251 200 ...
```

I want to convert it into a matrix like below:

```
 num [1:86, 1:15] 66.8 84.6 136.4 105 103 ...
```

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: `as.matrix(new.dataframe)` ?

Comment: It's working! Thank you.